# placing a view who's rotated proprely

Tags: android, view, rotation

i am making a card game, i have a View class that represent a card,
when i'm placing it in my ViewGroup who is horizontal, everything is working well.
when i rotate it to say 90 degrees, and placing it within a vertical ViewGroup,
that's when things do not go as well.

[image]

this is a depiction of the situtation, the first image is what i want to show,
the second is what actually shows..
the code i use for it goes like this:
  `Card c = new Card()
c.setRotation(90)`
and on the ViewGroup:

```
Card child = (Card)getChildAt(i);
measureChild(....
child.layout(0,y,child.getMeasuredWidth(),y+child.getMeasuredHeight());
```

i realized that because of the rotation i need to recompute the required x and y coordinates so it i could control the appearance of the view
but i could not find any answer to it.
one thing i did try was to calculate the difference between the height and width of that view, and dividing it by 2, and shifting the view x and y 
accordingly, which seemed to work, but when i changed the size of the view 
that formula didn't work anymore, it seemed that know i need to divide it by 4(?)
very confusing... 
any help will be appreciated!